# Could a planet have 1/2 the Earth’s mass but 1 g surface gravity?

Tags: planets, gravity, moons

So, we have a captured planet/moon orbiting a gas giant in the habitable zone. It is akin to prehistoric Mars, its geological activity having been maintained by constant tidal flexing from the gas giant. It is half the mass of earth, but knowing that the volume of a planet affects its surface gravity, could it still experience surface gravity of 1 g?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think this question has been asked. Or very nearly.

Comment: IMHO, sometimes the magic of creating a new world is the *newness* of it.  Having lower gravity creates difficulties, but difficulties are the things that make a story come to life.  If you've never read [Forever War](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Forever_War), I highly recommend it.  The author goes to some length in describing how the conditions on the planetoid they are on (low gravity, extreme cold) make life there... interesting.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes.

Surface gravity depends on the mass of the planet and its radius, according to the formula $g=Gm/r^2$.

If you put half the mass of Earth in $1/\sqrt{2}$ of its radius, the surface gravity will be the same.

Of course this would alter the density of the planet significantly, needing complete different materials to make it possible.

The average density would increase by a factor $\sqrt{2}$, which is not out of the realm of physics: 7.7 $kg/dm^3$ is a bit less than the density of iron.

Comment: If some of the iron in the core (30%?) were replaced by chemically analogous osmium, you'd get your density increase...

Comment: Or a larger core? Perhaps more similar to Mercury?

Comment: @user98816 That will work, but it depends on how many variables you want to worry about on your world. As the core gets larger, the mantle gets thinner and/or hotter. If your goal is human habitability, that might matter. That's one reason why Zeiss Ikon's idea has merit - it allows you to have a smaller version of Earth that is as believably like Earth as possible.

Comment: In theory yes. But for that to be happening you would need to have abundance of elements heavier than Ni/Fe which seems improbable. AND you would need to have little additional material getting trapped in the gravity pit of the forming planet otherwise you may end up with a super Earth. Overall an improbable combination.

Comment: @DuncanDrake on [physics.se] it's improbable. On [worldbuilding.se] where the question is not tagged [tag:science-based] or [tag:hard-science], it's probable if the OP wants it to be. Remember our goal from the [help/on-topic], "Worldbuilding Stack Exchange is a site ... to get help creating imaginary worlds. World building includes geography, culture and creatures for the world, not to mention magic and planetary physics, in short, everything from the physics underlying your reality to the entire universe you want to build."

Comment: @DuncanDrake As long as you don't require conforming to real science, there are multiple possible explanations for a dense planet. Fore-runner race that had large scale element transmutation (they transmuted a Jovian type planet for whatever reason), powerful magic using civilization (human or otherwise), Von Neuman robots that did it as part of making all mass into paperclips (look up universal paperclips), etc.

Comment: @ZeissIkon I'd skip osmium and go with a near-pure iron/nickel planet. Iron (and nickel) are way more abundant than osmium or even lead; nickel is a bit denser than iron. Iron meteorites are known; osmium is a big handwave. Iron is the 2nd most abundant solid element in the solar system by mass, half as abundant as carbon. Solid carbon is rare, as it tends to form CO2 gas. Oxygen is 1.5 times as common as carbon and tends to react chemically with everything. Next most common solid element is silicon; rocky planet's crusts are mainly SiO2.  wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundance_of_the_chemical_elements

Comment: Questions without those tags might not *require* scientifically plausible answers, but surely it's still useful to *say* if something is scientifically implausible, so that the OP can know that and make an informed choice. (And if we don't care about scientific plausibility then why care that osmium is chemically analogous to iron in the first place?)

Comment: @JBH Fine. Just pointing something out that could be integrated in the answer to make it more complete. Then it's up to OP to make an informed decision about their world.

Comment: @JBH I don't think even it's that improbable: a flyby by another star could send a Mercury-like planet to a Goldilocks-style orbit, and alter the orbits of every other asteroid and comet of that solar system so that, after a few million years you end up with a planet which is almost a naked iron core with a thin veil of a crust, with water and atmosphere provided by after-flyby late bombardment. Space is big. Surely there are several dozens planets in this very galaxy who will fit the bill.

Comment: 7.7 grams/cc is not all that high. The Earth's core's density ranges from 9.9 and 12.2 grams/cc -- and that includes some lighter elements. (That the density is that low indicates the presence of some lighter elements.)  Even iron compresses under high enough pressures. There is no need for exotic elements here. A larger core and smaller mantle is all that is needed. Note that gravitational acceleration at the Earth's core-mantle boundary is a bit over 10 m/s^2, which is higher than at the surface.

Comment: @DuncanDrake Actually, that's part of the problem with the changing culture of this Stack. It makes the *science* of the answer more complete, but since the OP didn't ask for that level of science, what it's really doing is muddying the water and failing to meet the OP's expectations. This Stack really isn't physics-lite. If the OP didn't ask for a full-science answer, then that should be respected and taken into account when answering.

Comment: The Earth is *already* the densest planet in the solar system, so you'd need a really unusual elemental makeup to get an even denser planet.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Earth, Venus and Mercury have almost the same density, Mars is a bit lighter. The other planets are big enough and cold enough that they can hold onto lighter substances than those that form the Earth: Ice for Uranus & Neptune, and even Hydrogen for Jupiter & Saturn. If the (supposed) impact that stripped off a large part of the Earth's mantle to form the Moon had removed more matter, the Earth would now be smaller & denser. Iron asteroids are known, and at least one exoplanet of twice the density of Earth is known https://www.space.com/11544-densest-alien-planet-55cancrie.html

Comment: kg/dm³ , cringe.

Answer (score 9):

L.Dutch's answer gives you the basic idea. At half the mass with a surface gravity of approximately Earth normal your planet has a radius of $2^{-1/2}$, a volume of $2^{-3/2}$ (0.35356) and a density of $(2^{-1/2+3/2}) = 2^{1/2}$... all as multiples of Earth's values. Since Earth has a density of approximately $5.495\ kg/L$ your planet clocks in at around $7.772\ kg/L$. That's a bit higher, but not unachievable.

Lots of comments about increasing the core size or density, but I think that's a non-starter. Earth's core accounts for only about $1/60$ of our mass, so your planet's core would have to be much larger by comparison and significantly more dense than our iron/nickel core to make much difference. The big payoff comes further up.

A little over 70% of the Earth's mass is in the Mantle, and the second most abundant element in there is magnesium. That's pretty wasteful considering that magnesium is a very light material. If we were able to removal all of the magnesium and replace it with more iron, the average density of our planet would increase quite a bit. What if we replaced most of the magnesium with manganese which is more than 4 times heavier by volume? OK the compounds aren't quite as much higher in density (some are lower, but we'll ignore those) so perhaps not. But you could simply siphon off all of those magnesium compounds to sell on the galactic gem market.

I'd say that simply changing the composition of the mantle can do most of what you need. Increase the iron in the mantle, add some more nickel in there too. Liberally sprinkle the crust with deposits of heavy metals. Maybe write in a collision with a heavy element asteroid in the planet's history - it's always fun to find new sources of Iridium for example.

Comment: Most of the iron in the mantle would have sunk into the core due to planetary differentiation, so that's a non-starter. Besides, it doesn't matter where the iron resides due to Newton's shell theorem. A smaller mantle and a larger core is exactly what is needed, and does so without resorting to uncommon elements. Iron and nickel are relatively common elements. Manganese is not. Iridium is even further from being common. If you want an uncommon dense element that doesn't sink to the core, I suggest uranium. Uranium coins would add a twist to the phrase "money burning a hole in ones pocket".

Comment: Maybe a little tungsten would go a long way.  Even its ores are heavy.  Wolframite is >7kg/L.